# Accessing methods after inheritance error

Tags: c++, inheritance, base-class

I am using inheritance for my code. ChangeRequest is my base class. The code is as follows.

ChangeRequest.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class ChangeRequest
{
int swapDay;
int newDay;
public:
void setSwapDay(int newDay);
int getSwapDay();

void setNewDay(int newDay);
int getNewDay();
```

};

ChangeRequest.cpp

```
#include "ChangeDutyRequest.h"

void ChangeRequest::setSwapDay(int newDay)
{
    swapDay = newDay;
}

int ChangeRequest::getSwapDay()
{
    return swapDay;
}

void ChangeRequest::setNewDay(int day)
{
    newDay = day;
}   

int ChangeRequest::getNewDay()
{
    return newDay;
}
```

The code below is for the derived class. SwapDuty
SwapDuty.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ChangeRequest.h"

using namespace std;

class SwapDuty: public ChangeRequest
{
    string requester;
    public:
    void setRequester(string member);
    string getRequester();
};
```

SwapDuty.cpp

```
   #include "SwapDuty.h"

    void SwapDuty::setRequester(string member)
    {
        requester = member;
    }

    string SwapDuty::getRequester()
    {
        return requester;
    }
```

when I compile and access the requester attribute using getRequester(). I get the following error.

```
'class ChangeRequest' has no member named 'getRequester'
```

This is how I used my code

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

```
    SwapDuty newSwapDutyRequest;
        for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++ )
        {
            if(tempList[i].getPersonToPerform().getName() == loginMember)
            {
                newSwapDutyRequest.setRequester(loginMember);   
                newSwapDutyRequest.setSwapDay(swapDay);
                newSwapDutyRequest.setNewDutyDay(daySwapWith);
                break;
            }
        }
        changeList.push_back(newSwapDutyRequest);

cout << changeList[1].getRequester() << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is type of changeList?

Although you have created an object of the derived class, I suspect that you are pushing it into the container of the base class.  Possibly you are getting few warnings before this error as well, because of pushing derived object into the container of type base.

If you want to make a container of base class and push in the derived class objects you need to work with the pointers to the objects not the objects themselves.

Comment: + to declare pure virtual function `getRequester` in `ChangeRequest` class

Answer (score 0):

Where is your class `ChangeDutyRequest`? You don't show it. Maybe you forgot to inherit it from the correct base or invoke it incorrectly?

Show fuller code sample

Comment: sorry ChangeDutyRequest is ChangeRequest I typed the code in incorrectly.

Comment: But `ChangeRequest` has no `getRequester` method. Inheriting it with `SwapDuty` doesn't add the method to the base class, only the child class - you understand it?

Comment: The object I create is from the SwapDuty class and I ask to getRequester from that and it gives me this error. But SwapDuty does have the requester attribute.

Comment: @Peter: but the error complain about `ChangeReqest` so you're doing it wrong. Can you show the code you use to create object and access teh method?

Comment: @zaharpopov: this is not an answer but a comment to the question and should be posted accordingly